# java runtime.freememory() not matching with jconsole output

Tags: java, jvm, jconsole

I was going through a weird problem. I have multiple JVMs running and I need to get the memory usage details of them. when I get the details by `Runtime.getFreeMemory()` and compare it to jconsole output there is a huge difference. what might be the problem?? I am getting incorrect details when I use `Runtime.getFreeMemory()` or

```java
ManagementFactory.getMemoryMXBean().getHeapMemoryUsage().getMax() - ManagementFactory.getMemoryMXBean().getHeapMemoryUsage().getUsed();
```

what might be the problem?? Any suggestions / comments greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: What discrepancy do you see? BTW Have you tried VisualVM?

Comment: Sorry, ManagementFactory.getMemoryMXBean().getHeapMemoryUsage().getMax() - ManagementFactory.getMemoryMXBean().getHeapMemoryUsage().getUsed(); reflects with jconsole where as Runtime.getFreeMemory() isnt

Comment: `free = total - used` of course. Can you give us some numbers?

Answer (score 0):

`Runtime.getFreeMemory()` tells you the amount of memory left out of what has been *allocated*.  It is `Runtime.totalMemory()` - the currently used memory.  `Runtime.maxMemory()` is the total memory you've indicated that the JVM can allocate (`-Xmx`).  It can be more than `Runtime.totalMemory()`.  You are probably looking at the difference between max memory and used in jconsole.  To test this, try setting (`-Xms`) to the same as (`-Xmx`) which will cause the JVM to allocate the maximum memory at the start.